# how to start ionic app and nodejs server together

Tags: node.js, express, ionic-framework

I have ionic application and nodejs server app. Both application clubbed as a single application.
At present I start application by two cmd (one for starting the nodejs server[node server], next for starting the ionic app ['ionic serve'])

I just need to how to start the applications together in single command
please help

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way to execute multiple commands at once, then you can do something like this:

```
node server; ionic serve
```

Or:

```
node server && ionic serve
```

The first one executes `node server` first and then `ionic serve` without checking whether `node server` had any errors or not and the second one will only continue with `ionic serve` if `node server` is successful. There are more options to choose from and you can find them [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334994/which-one-is-better-using-or-to-execute-multiple-commands-in-one-line).